# HTTPS PUT Request using djangorestframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send an HTTPS PUT request to a RESTful API Django web service using a djangorestframework (DRF: http://django-rest-framework.org/) View.  I cannot get this to work due to Django's Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) protection.

The PUT request is intended to allow unauthenticated users to add a resource.

What I have considered/tried:

1. Disabling CSRF -- not acceptable.  The API runs on the same Django instance as the non-API service.  Disabling CSRF protection is too much risk.
2. Using the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header on the PUT request (I control the clients).  Doesn't work -- I still get the CSRF error.
3. Using the `@crsf_exempt` decorator on the PUT view.  I would if I could -- the framework defines a class, not a view.

My current best option is to write PUT views myself without using DRF's View class.  I can then use the `@crsf_exempt` decorator successfully.

I'd like to use DRF's View class -- but cannot see how.  Can you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to James Cran Wellward, I was also able to solve this issue by using the method_decorator.

```
class ExampleView(ResponseMixin,View):
  renderers=DEFAULT_RENDERERS
  def get(self,request):
    response=Response(200,{'msg':'called via GET'})
    return self.render(response)
  def post(self,request):
    response=Response(200,{'msg':'called via POST'})
    return self.render(response)
  @method_decorator(csrf_exempt):
  def dispatch(self,*args,**kwargs):
    return super(EampleView,self).dispatch(*args,**kwargs)
```

and then test it:

```
curl -X GET http://www.example.com/rest/exampleview/
```

returns:

```
{msg: 'called via GET'}
```

and

```
curl -X POST http://www.example.com/rest/exampleview/
```

returns:

```
{msg: 'called via POST'}
```

HTH. see the [original post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-rest-framework/JCf4MwNtfwM).

Comment: Since I asked this question I have moved over to django-tastypie -- so I can't easily verify this.  But, your answer looks convincing!